# Magento 2 Rest Api customer associated with the email or not?

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api

I am checking the rest api regarding customer has been existed or not with the email. I found an API in the swagger tool i.e POST /V1/customers/isEmailAvailable

> 1. At Swagger Tool:-

[image: First Screen shot]

> 2. At Post Man APP:-

[image: second Screen shot]

> 3. At Magento Admin End:-

[image: 3rd Screen shot]

my question is customer is existing with the email but return false instead of true. whether it is a correct? please clarify.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually this returns that the email you entered is available to register or not, if it found the email in the database it returns false else it returns true that yes you can use this email for new registration.

And yes your output is correct.

Comment: one small doubt how do u know whether this api is used before registration?

Comment: i just uses a example scope of registration . You can use it anywhere. Registration is a good example to make it understand

Comment: For more example you can use this before forget password action, you can check if the entered email is available or not.